# Using a variable in multiple views

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm working with flash builder (flex) and wanna assign value to a variable in a view and use that variable in other views.
but the problem is when i define for example an array in one view it's undefined in other views and i cant use value of that variable in my functions.
whats the solution?

Comment: You can use static variable

Comment: First, read my post about how to components should communicate in a Flex application: http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component .  A static variable should work as @ZuzEL recommended.  You can also make use of a dependency injection framework such as Swiz or Robotlegs in order to share data between views

Comment: It doesn't work. still its undefined.

Comment: Thanks. i read this and see what will happen.

Comment: you can create global class, And define your variables there.. so that you can access it by importing that class in your views.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a reference the view which has your variable in the other view . 
Make sure that your variable is public and bindable.

Comment: +1 because this is accurate info.  It is not, however, a comprehensive answer.

Comment: how can i create a reference for my variable? what do you mean?